# Submitting a form fails, but because views.auth_login (not related to my form) didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: python, django

OK, so I have a functional auth_login setup. But it's unrelated to my `Articles` model, and `ArticleForm` ModelForm. However, when I try to create a new article on the local website, I get an error related to views.auth_login even though auth_login isn't referenced anywhere (to my knowledge) in my Article stuff: `The view home.views.auth_login didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` Usually, an error like that means that you're not returning an actual response in a view definition, but I do. The real question is why `home.views.auth_login` is being called instead of `home.views.add_article`. Here's my code:

### home/models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1024)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

### home/forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Article

class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "password"]


class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['headline', 'content']
```

### home/views.py

```
def auth_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        else:
            # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
            return HttpResponse('Invalid username / password. :( Try again? <3')

    else:
        loginform = LoginForm()

        context = {
            'loginform': loginform
        }
        return render(request, 'home/login.html', context)

def add_article(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ArticleForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            article = form.save()
            article.save()
            # todo change to view article page
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid Inputs. :( Try again? <3')
    else:
        form = ArticleForm()

        context = {
            'form': form,
        }

        return render(request, 'home/add_article.html', context)
```

### home/urls.py

```
...
urlpatterns = [
    # match to ''
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.auth_login, name='login'),
    url(r'^home/$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^articles/add/$', views.add_article, name='add_article')
]
```

### home/templates/home/add_article.html

```
<h2> Add an Article </h2>
<form action="/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="addArticle" class="btn col2"/>
</form>
```

### Results / Problem

When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/add`, fill out my simple form, and click submit, I get:

```
The view home.views.auth_login didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

File "/Users/hills/Desktop/code/django-beanstalk/ebenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/hills/Desktop/code/django-beanstalk/ebenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/Users/hills/Desktop/code/django-beanstalk/ebenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  198.                 "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)

Exception Type: ValueError at /
Exception Value: The view home.views.auth_login didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

But I can't figure out why `home.views.auth_login` is being called instead of `home.views.add_article`. I've tried deleting and recreating all db tables (`python manage.py flush`, then `python manage.py makemigrations`, then `python manage.py migrate`), and I've even tried independently writing an independent Article2 model / form / template set, but I get the same error. --> Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your form is submitting to the root of your website, so that's why it's hitting `auth_login` instead of `add_article`.

Change `<form action="/" method="post">` to just `<form method="POST">`. I assume the other error (no HttpResponse object) is just a side effect of POSTing to `auth_login`.

Comment: Fantastic! I didn't realize <form action='/'> did that. Thank you!!

Comment: You can also do something like `<form action="{% url 'add_article' %}">`, to be more specific about the form's action. Leaving the action parameter out , the form will submit to "itself" or the current, active page.